# How can I create a function which will take a date and return schedules based on time condition

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, filter

This is my database structure:

```
[
    {
        "schedule_time": "2021-05-17 12:39:29",
        "slot": "L",
        "item_date": "2021-05-18"
    },
    {
        "schedule_time": "2021-05-17 12:47:53",
        "slot": "D",
        "item_date": "2021-05-18"
    },
    {
        "schedule_time": "2021-05-18 13:55:22",
        "slot": "D",
        "item_date": "2021-05-19"
    },
    {
        "schedule_time": "2021-05-19 16:09:15",
        "slot": "L",
        "item_date": "2021-05-20"
    },
    {
        "schedule_time": "2021-05-19 16:11:55",
        "slot": "L",
        "item_date": "2021-05-20"
    },
```

I want to create a function that will take **item_date** and it will show how many schedules are between 9am to 12am. 12am to 3pm, 3pm to 6pm, 6pm to 9pm on previous days. if you look at the database the item_date and schedule_date are not the same. That's why I want the previous day's schedules listed in an array.

I have created a function it's only returning 9am to 12am data. I want the schedules together in an array.

```
  function schedulesList (date){
        let dbItemDate = date;
        let otherDayArray = schedules.filter(num => num.item_date !== dbItemDate); // not equal because I want other dates schedules not the exact date
        let times = otherDayArray?.filter(num => num.schedule_time.split(' ')[1] >= '12:00:00' && num.schedule_time.split(' ')[1] <= '14:00:00');
        console.log('9am to 12pm', times.length, 'schedules') //
    }
```

The expected result should be similar to this:

```
[
'9am to 12pm' : 2,
'12pm to 3pm' : 0,
'3pm to 6pm' : 1,
'6pm to 9pm' : 3,
]
```

Comment: Please provide expected rusult

Comment: The expected result should be like this or similar: `[
'9am to 12pm' : 2,
'12pm to 3pm' : 0,
'3pm to 6pm' : 1,
'6pm to 9pm' : 3,
]`

Comment: Please include all relevant code and a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt to do this yourself first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you've stored the given input array in a variable called `data`.

```js
let data = [{
    "schedule_time": "2021-05-17 12:39:29",
    "slot": "L",
    "item_date": "2021-05-18"
  },
  {
    "schedule_time": "2021-05-17 12:47:53",
    "slot": "D",
    "item_date": "2021-05-18"
  },
  {
    "schedule_time": "2021-05-18 13:55:22",
    "slot": "D",
    "item_date": "2021-05-19"
  },
  {
    "schedule_time": "2021-05-19 16:09:15",
    "slot": "L",
    "item_date": "2021-05-21"
  },
  {
    "schedule_time": "2021-05-19 16:11:55",
    "slot": "L",
    "item_date": "2021-05-20"
  }
];

//function to get the final results
let getScheduleCounter = (date) => {
  let scheduleCounter = {
    '9_12': [],
    '12_3': [],
    '3_6': [],
    '6_9': []
  };

  data.forEach(sch => {
    if (sch.item_date !== date) {
      updateScheduledCounter(sch, scheduleCounter);
    }
  });

  return scheduleCounter;
}

//function to get the count and update in scheduleCounter
let updateScheduledCounter = (sch, scheduleCounter) => {
  let time = sch.schedule_time.split(' ')[1];
  switch (!!time) {
    case (time <= '12:00:00'):
      scheduleCounter['9_12']++;
      break;

    case (time >= '12:00:00' && time <= '15:00:00'):
      scheduleCounter['12_3']++;
      break;

    case (time >= '15:00:00' && time <= '18:00:00'):
      scheduleCounter['3_6']++;
      break;

    case (time >= '18:00:00' && time <= '21:00:00'):
      scheduleCounter['6_9']++;
      break;
  }
}

let schedules = getScheduleCounter("2021-05-20");
console.log('schedules: ', schedules);
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the following approach to the solution

```js
const schedules = [
{"schedule_time": "2021-05-17 12:39:29","slot": "L","item_date": "2021-05-18"},
{"schedule_time": "2021-05-17 12:47:53","slot": "D","item_date": "2021-05-18"},
{"schedule_time": "2021-05-18 13:55:22","slot": "D","item_date": "2021-05-19"},
{"schedule_time": "2021-05-19 16:09:15","slot": "L","item_date": "2021-05-20"},
{"schedule_time": "2021-05-19 16:11:55","slot": "L","item_date": "2021-05-20"}];

const hours = [
{hoursName: '9am to 12pm', from: 9, to: 12},
{hoursName: '12pm to 3pm', from: 12, to: 15},
{hoursName: '3pm to 6pm', from: 15, to: 18},
{hoursName: '6pm to 9pm', from: 18, to: 21}];

const targetDate = new Date("2021-05-20");

const previousItems = schedules.filter(({ schedule_time }) => {
  const scheduleTime = new Date(schedule_time);
  return scheduleTime < targetDate;
});

const result = previousItems.reduce((acc, { schedule_time }) => {
  const scheduleTime = new Date(schedule_time);
  const targetHour = scheduleTime.getHours();
  const { hoursName } = hours.find(({ from, to }) => (targetHour >= from) && (targetHour < to));
  acc[hoursName] = (acc[hoursName] ?? 0) + 1;
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height: 100%!important; top: 0}
```